# Custom metric for Keras model, using Tensorflow 2.1

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.x, keras-metrics

I would like to add a custom metric to model with Keras, I'm debugging my working code and I don't find a method to do the operations I need.

The problem could be described as a multi classification trough logistic multinomial regression.
The custom metric I would like to implement is this:

```
(1/Number_of_Classes)*(TruePositivesClass1/TotalElementsClass1 + TruePositivesClass2/TotalElementsClass2 + ... + TruePositivesClassN/TotalElementsClassN)
```

Where Number_of_Classes must be calculate from batch, i.e something like `np.unique(y_true).count()` and
and every summation item would be something like

```
len(np.where(y_true==class_i,1,0) == np.where(y_pred==class_i,1,0) )/np.where(y_true==class_i,1,0).sum()
```

In terms of confusion matrix (in the minimal form of 2 variables)

```
        True    False
True     15      3
False    12      1
```

The formula would be `0.5*(15)/(15+12) + 0.5*(1/(1+3))=0.4027`

The code could be something like

```
def custom_metric(y_true,y_pred):

    total_classes = Unique(y_true) #How calculate total unique elements?
    summation = 0
    for _ in unique_value_on_target:

        # calculates Number of y_predict that are _
        true_predics_of_class = Count(y_predict,_) 

        # calculates total number of items of class _ in batch y_true
        true_values = Count(y_true,_) 

        value = true_predicts/true_values
       summation + = value
    return summation
```

My preprocessed data is a numpy array  like `x=[v1,v2,v3,v4,...,vn]`, and my
objetive column is a nompy array `y=[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1 ,..., 0, 1]`

then, they are converted to tensors:

```
x_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
y_train = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y))
```

Then, they are converted to tensorflow dataset objects:

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train),
                                tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train)))
```

Later, I take a iterator:

```
 train_itr = iter(
          train_ds.shuffle(len(y_train) * 5, reshuffle_each_iteration=True).batch(len(y_train)))
```

and last, I take one element of iterator and train

```
x_train, y_train = train_itr.get_next()
model.fit(x=x_train, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
          callbacks=[custom_callback], validation_data=test_itr.get_next())
```

So, since objects are dataset iterators, I can't find functions to operate them as I would like, in order to get the custom metric described.

[image: type(y_pred)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want calculate **average recall wrt multiclass in the batch**, here is my example code using `numpy` and `tensorflow`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y_t = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
y_p = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)

def average_recall(y_true, y_pred):
    # Get indexes of both labels and predictions
    labels = np.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    predictions = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    # Get confusion matrix from labels and predictions
    confusion_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions).numpy()
    # Get number of all true positives in each class
    all_true_positives = np.diag(confusion_matrix)
    # Get number of all elements in each class
    all_class_sum = np.sum(confusion_matrix, axis=1)
    # Get rid of classes that don't show in batch
    zero_index = np.where(all_class_sum == 0)[0]
    all_true_positives = np.delete(all_true_positives, zero_index)
    all_class_sum = np.delete(all_class_sum, zero_index)

    print("confusion_matrix:\n {},\n all_true_positives:\n {},\n all_class_sum:\n {}".format(
                                            confusion_matrix, all_true_positives, all_class_sum))
    # Average TruePositives / TotalElements wrt all classes that show in batch
    return np.mean(all_true_positives / all_class_sum)

avg_recall = average_recall(y_t, y_p)
print(avg_recall)
```

Outputs:

```
confusion_matrix:
 [[1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2]],
 all_true_positives:
 [1 1 2],
 all_class_sum:
 [1 2 2]
0.8333333333333334
```

Implement using only tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y_t = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)
y_p = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)

def average_recall(y_true, y_pred):
    # Get indexes of both labels and predictions
    labels = tf.argmax(y_true, axis=1)
    predictions = tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    # Get confusion matrix from labels and predictions
    confusion_matrix = tf.math.confusion_matrix(labels, predictions)
    # Get number of all true positives in each class
    all_true_positives = tf.linalg.diag_part(confusion_matrix)
    # Get number of all elements in each class
    all_class_sum = tf.reduce_sum(confusion_matrix, axis=1)
    # Get rid of classes that don't show in batch
    mask = tf.not_equal(all_class_sum, tf.constant(0))
    all_true_positives = tf.boolean_mask(all_true_positives, mask)
    all_class_sum = tf.boolean_mask(all_class_sum, mask)

    print("confusion_matrix:\n {},\n all_true_positives:\n {},\n all_class_sum:\n {}".format(
                                            confusion_matrix, all_true_positives, all_class_sum))
    # Average TruePositives / TotalElements wrt all classes that show in batch
    return tf.reduce_mean(all_true_positives / all_class_sum)

avg_recall = average_recall(y_t, y_p)
print(avg_recall)
```

Outputs:

```
confusion_matrix:
 [[1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 2]],
 all_true_positives:
 [1 1 2],
 all_class_sum:
 [1 2 2]
tf.Tensor(0.8333333333333334, shape=(), dtype=float64)
```

Reference:

[tf.math.confusion_matrix](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/confusion_matrix)

[Calculate precision and recall for multiclass classification using confusion matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51296/how-do-you-calculate-precision-and-recall-for-multiclass-classification-using-co)

Comment: yes! thats perfect. My problem was not the numpy implementation, my problem was the keras implementation. I can't find keras.backend functions that allows me to do it. I'll eit my question

Comment: @LuisFelipe Seems you are happy about the answer but just be clear, did my answer solve your problem or you want keras implementation instead?

Comment: i would like to have a keras implementation. I used this metric with eager mode and converting tensors to numpy arrays, but this is slower. Keras implementation would be awesome

Comment: @I add `tf` implementation too, check the answer!

Comment: i did everything equal, but I didnt find any equivalent to np.delete. You did it great thanks!@Mr.ForExample

Comment: @LuisFelipe no problem, have a good day : )